# Powershell: Change properties of a Microsoft failover cluster group aka role

Tags: powershell, cluster-computing, failover

I created a generic service group (or role as it is displayed in the GUI) via powershell
`Add-ClusterGenericServiceRole`
Basically it is the AppReadiness service. Everything went fine so far.
I would like to change some properties of this group, NOT of the underlying service.
I can get all the properties of the group via `Get-Clustergroup -Name .... | select-object *`
I see the properties which I would like to change,

```
FailoverPeriod         : 1
FailoverThreshold      : 99
```

These properties are also visible in the GUI on the failover tab
When I try

```
$cluGroup = Get-ClusterGroup -Name ......
```

and create

```
$param1 = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.ClusterParameter -Property $cluGroup,FailoverThreshold,55
```

it gives me the error:

```
New-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Collections.IDictionary' required by parameter 'Property'. Specified method is not supported.
```

The error is the same if I change it to `Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.ClusterResource`
In the MS docu they have an example like that also they modify a cluster resource but according to the docu the scriplet takes also `Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.ClusterGroup` as an input.
The error is still the same if `Get-ClusterResource ....` and change it to

```
$param1 = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.ClusterResource -Property $cluResource,Description,"Some text"
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a ticket at Microsoft and they came back with the following working answer:

```
(Get-ClusterGroup -Name "Testgroup").FailoverPeriod=12
```

Basically, these "things" which are part of the cluster group are considered "properties" and not parameters and can therefore not be modified with the
`Set-ClusterParameter` scriptlet.

All credits to Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `-Property` parameter expects a hashtable, not an array. So it needs `Key = Value` format. You should be able to do:

```
$param1 = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.ClusterParameter -Property @{'FailoverThreshold'=55}
```

That should give you a ClusterParameter object with the property `FailoverThreshold` having a value of `55`.

Comment: thx for your fast reply. I tried it and the error changed :-)
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not 
registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
That is also true if try to change some other property like the "Description"  or the "Name" of the cluster group

Comment: Taking a closer look at the command:
$param1 = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.ClusterParameter -Property @{'FailoverThreshold'=55}
Where did the variable $clugroup go which basically contains the object I would like to change a property on

Comment: This creates a new object, it doesn't modify one.